# beamer two columns figure and formula

Tags: beamer, two-column

I am trying to do a beamer slide with two columns, one with an image and the other with a matrix more or less big. The code that I have is the following

```
\begin{frame}{Frame}
  \frametitle{Minimal grid example}
  \begin{columns}
    \column{0.4\textwidth}
      \includegraphics[scale=0.2]{image.pdf}
      \column{0.4\textwidth}
      \begin{equation}
        \begin{pmatrix}
          0 && 0 && 1 && 0 && 0 && 0 && 0 && 0 \\
          0 && 0 && 0 && 0 && 0 && 1 && 0 && 0 \\
          t && -r^* && 0 && 0 && 0 && 0 && 0 && 0 \\
          0 && 0 && 0 && 0 && 0 && 0 && 0 && 1 \\
          0 && 0 && 0 && 0 && 0 && 0 && 1 && 0 \\
          r && t* && 0 && 0 && 0 && 0 && 0 && 0 \\
          0 && 0 && 0 && 0 && 1 && 0 && 0 && 0 \\
          0 && 0 && 0 && 1 && 0 && 0 && 0 && 0
        \end{pmatrix}.
      \end{equation}
 \end{columns}
\end{frame}
```

but for some reason, the matrix is stretched to fill the whole right
column. How can I manipulate the size of the formula?

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 2):

```
\documentclass[demo]{beamer}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{Frame}
  \frametitle{Minimal grid example}
  \begin{columns}
    \column{0.5\textwidth}
    \centering
      \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{image.pdf}
      \column{0.5\textwidth}
      \setlength\arraycolsep{3pt}
      \begin{equation}
        \begin{pmatrix}
          0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
          0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
          t & -r^* & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
          0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
          0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
          r & t* & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
          0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
          0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0
        \end{pmatrix}.
      \end{equation}
 \end{columns}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]
I made three changes:

- replace `&&` with `&` (I don't understand of purpose of double ampersands, you only cross limit of normal matrix size -- 10 columns)
- reduce column separation in matrix
- change size of columns